# xaml How reference a dynamic resource not as a attribute but as an element

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have an image I need to use in my application in several places.  I want to define the image just once in a resource dictionary, and have my other xaml files just that definition.  I can The one thing I haven't bee able to figure out is how to reference something defined as a xaml element instead of a attributed inside of a xaml attribute.

Here is my ResourceDictionary

```
# resourceDictionary.xaml

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MyGradient" StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
    <GradientStop Color="#A5000000" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Image x:Key="MyImage" Source="MyGlyph.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
```

So in my xaml I know how to reference the gradient as an attribute of a control object

```
<TextBlock Text="Sample Text" Background="{DynamicResource MessageGradient}"/>
```

But what I want to figure out his how to reference the Image which is a full blown control object. This example just creates a button that has the text "{DynamicResource MyImage}" in the button instead of the image.

```
<!-- Want MyImage to be content of the button -->
<Button>
   {DynamicResource MyImage}
</Button>
```

Is there a simple way to do this, or will have I have to create a control template that contains just my image, and then in my xaml have a image tag that uses the control template?

Answer (score 5):

Since you want the image to be the content of the button, you should be able to bind that to the `Content` property:

```
<Button Content="{DynamicResource MyImage}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<!-- Want MyImage to be content of the button --> 
<Button> 
   <DynamicResource  ResourceKey="MyImage"/>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put an Image as Background of any control

```
  <Button  Content="My Button">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush   ImageSource="MyGlyph.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```